# Tag Errors Configuring AllJoyn Java Environment on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, tags, alljoyn

I have been able to build the AllJoyn C++ base with no issues on Ubuntu. However, when I attempt to configure the Java environment, I am receiving the following errors:

```
error: no summary or caption for table
error: element not closed: ul
error: tag not allowed here: <a>
error: tag not allowed here: <li>
```

When attempting to build, I receive the occasional warning, but the code itself appears to be fine.

I take it I don't have a package for generating documentation, but all of the necessary pre-requisites appear to be working correctly. This is 32-bit Ubuntu 13.04 running the Oracle JDK 1.8.0 with AllJoyn 14.02.00.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of AllJoyn only officially supports JDK 1.6.  Reverting to the officially supported JDK has corrected the issue.

Answer via georgen [here](https://ask.allseenalliance.org/question/148/tag-errors-configuring-java-build-environment-on-ubuntu/).